# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular

Encontre la respuesta en ingles [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form/39152110#39152110)
Segun debo agregar ReactiveFormsModule en mis imports, ya lo hice y adicionalmente exporte ReactiveFormsModule, pero me sigue dando el mismo erro!

Este es el error

```
    Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("

<div class="modal-body">
  <form [ERROR ->][formGroup]="todoForm" (ngSubmit)="saveTodo()" class=" "> 

    <div class="form-group"> 
"): ng:///AppModule/TodoFormComponent.html@8:8
```

Este es impor de la librerias

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Gracias

Comment: ReactiveFormsModule, lo estàs importando en tù modulo principal tambièn?

Comment: no ese era el problema gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu app.module.ts (o module que contenga el componente)

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
//...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
})
```

Comment: muchas gracias el problema era que me faltaban los imports